# How a C++ project in visual studio-8 can be build and run from other C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project(say code.sln) and another project(say test.sln);
Now I want to build and run project code.sln from my test project. Can anyone help me to write this code in C++?

Comment: code project is .exe file. It's separate application. I would like to compile and execute it from other progam

Answer (score 0):

Your code.sln needs to be compiled to a .lib or .dll and referenced by test.sln.

Answer (score 0):

If your "code" project is a static library or DLL, you can right-click on the solution, select "Add", then "Add Existing Project".  From there if you go to the properties of "test", go to "Common Properties", then "Add New Reference" and you'll be able to select your library.